# Testing incoming pull requests using sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, pull-request

This is about **BitBucket**, may or may not apply on others. And I'd prefer to do it using **SourceTree** or any other GUI tool.

Suppose I have a repository `izharaazmi/repo` and somebody `forks` it which creates his repo, say `developer/repo`. Now after making his changes he `commits` and sends a `pull request`.

Now I want to test his submission before I approve it and merge it to the main repository `izharaazmi/repo`. How can I do this in an easy way?

As there may be tens or even hundreds of difference developers sending pull requests depending on the size of the project, It is not possible to download each of them neither adding remote source for each.

**Additional note:** The Joomla community is already managing such scenario at significantly large scale, however they are on GitHub, if that makes any difference.